# Combine two lists in Excel, one underneath the other

Tags: excel, dynamic-arrays

I have two lists of products in Excel. Each list will be of varying length each month.

Is there a way to combine the two lists into a third list, with the second list being underneath the first?

I would like to do this avoiding macros.

I image this could be done using Dynamic Arrays, but I can't figure it out.

Please see an example below:

[image]

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution that works for me, where the lists are of variable length.

Using a similar scenario to Mardi-Louise's answer, I am using the following formula in cell F3, and then dragging down:

=IF(B3<>"",B3,OFFSET($D$3,ROW()-COUNTA($B$3:$B$7),0))

Explanation:

- So long as List 1 is not finished, it takes the value from List 1.
- Once List 1 is finished, it begins at the top of List 2, and uses an offset to move down.

[image]

Comment: this formula work for me :
` =IF(B3<>"",B3,OFFSET($D$3,ROW()-COUNTA($B$3:$B$7)-ROW($D$3) ,0)) `

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party, but for anyone still looking for this there's (now) a function for this in Excel 365: `vstack(array1;array2;...)`

Here is [Microsoft's page on it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c)

With the arrays as columns in tables you'll get dynamic lengths. It's also possible to combine `vstack()` with for example `unique()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before and used [this](https://www.get-digital-help.com/merge-three-columns-into-one-list-in-excel/) tutorial to help me. I attach the [example sheet](https://www.get-digital-help.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/merge-three-columns.xlsx) also, which provides the formula that may work for your problem.

See the image below for cell references - then try this:

**=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$7, ROWS(H2:$H$2)), IFERROR(INDEX($D$3:$D$4, ROWS(H2:$H$2)-ROWS($B$3:$B$7)), IFERROR(INDEX($F$3:$F$6, ROWS(H2:$H$2)-ROWS($B$3:$B$7)-ROWS($D$3:$D$4)), "")))**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It indeed is a good solution. However, in my particular use case, the length of the original lists are unknown. 

I am not sure how to adjust these formulae for such a case.

Answer (score 0):

I benefitted from Answer 2 with slightly different syntax. The ROW() function provides an output based on the absolute cell address when an output based on the relative position of the list is actually more generally applicable. I found the following syntax works better to reference the output of ROW() to the cell above the top cell of range D3:D8:

```
=IF(B3<>"",B3,OFFSET($D$2,ROW()-ROW($D$2)-COUNTA($B$3:$B$7),0))
```

Additionally, the COUNTA function can provide inconsistent results when cells in the range are not based on simple data but on the output of formulas which can be equal to 0 or blank without actually being empty. In that case COUNTIF often works better such as:

```
=IF(B3<>"",B3,OFFSET($D$2,ROW()-ROW($D$2)-COUNTIF($B$3:$B$7,"<>"&0),0))
```